# assigning value from a vector (of shared pointer) to a shared pointer cause segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, while-loop, shared-ptr

In my code, I have a `vector <vector <vector <vector <std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> > > > >` named `foosBoxes`. The nested vector has a role of simulating a physical boxes position. I also have a while loop which cause a segmentation fault:

```
vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> >::iterator fooit = foosBoxes[x][y][z].begin(); //x,y,z are valid integer
std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> aFoo;
while (fooit != foosBoxes[x][y][z].end()){
  aFoo = *fooit; //this cause segmentation fault
  fooit++;
  //some stuff which does not have an effect on fooit;
}
```

Some thing I have tried:
1. I have tried to use `aFoo = *fooit++` but this didn't work.
2. The segmentation fault occurs roughly after several thousandths loops which went on fine.
3. I have tried to valgrind the problem and valgrind went through the step.
4. In the loop that crashes, I have printed a running counter before and after the suspected line. when before the line, I get 8 printings (the size of the vector) and when after I get 7 printings.

How can I figure this out?

**Update:**
I have added a loop to run before the main loop:

```
int kkk = 1214
int c = 0;
while (c < foosBoxes[x][y][z].end()){
   aFoo = foosBoxes[x][y][z][c++];
   printf("%i\t, kkk);
   fflush(stdout);
}
```

Which yields the same results.

**Update:**
according to gdb:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x000000000043e400 in rotate (kkk=1214) at
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/tr1/boost_shared_ptr.h:153
>   153             dispose();

I think that the appropriate function in boost_shared_ptr.h is

```
void
  release() // nothrow                                                                                                                      
  {
    if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(&_M_use_count, -1) == 1)
      {
        dispose(); //this is line 153
#ifdef __GTHREADS
        _GLIBCXX_READ_MEM_BARRIER;
        _GLIBCXX_WRITE_MEM_BARRIER;
#endif
        if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(&_M_weak_count, -1) == 1)
          destroy();
      }
  }
```

`dispose()` is defined elsewhere in the file:

```
  // dispose() is called when _M_use_count drops to zero, to release                                                                        
  // the resources managed by *this.                                                                                                        
  virtual void
  dispose() = 0; // nothrow
```

Could it be that the reason is ill management of shared_ptr and I should switch back to regular pointer?

**Update:**
yet another test with similar result:

int kkk = 1214
int c = fooBoxes[x][y][z].size();
while (c >= 0){
   aFoo = foosBoxes[x][y][z][c--];
   printf("%i\t, kkk);
   fflush(stdout);
}

This time the program crush in the third iteration. Should the problem was with wrong allocation, then the program should have crush in the first iteration (in the opposite direction the program crashes in the first iteration).

Comment: From what you've said it sounds like some code somewhere else is invoking undefined behaviour. Have you tried running it with valgrind or similar tools for your platform?

Comment: @awoodland: yes I tried valgrind (number 3 on things I tried list) the problem is that valgeind survived this step...

Comment: Try enabling all sorts of debug modes (compiler-wise and library-wise) and try to reduce your code to a minimum to isolate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came to the conclusion that the problem was with the use `vector` is wrong since I update it through the code. I don't know how the memory management in `c++` works but I believe that some sort of overlapping between two vector occurred. I have switched to `set` and everything works now

Answer (score 1):

Run your code with libstdc++ in [debug mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html). It will do extra checks of iterators, containers and algorithms and hopefully will help to find the bug.

Comment: How do I run the libstdc++? I have gcc and g++ compilers on my machine.

Comment: Read [Using the Debug Mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch17s03.html#debug_mode.using.mode). To use the libstdc++ debug mode, compile your application with the compiler flag -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and rerun you code. Hopefully it will crash on some invalid action.

Comment: libstdc++ is a shared library implementing Standard C++ Library. It is shipped with g++ compiler.

Comment: I have tried that and got and error *attempt to compare a singular iterator to a past-the-end iterator* I am now trying to find the cause of that (the specific function is not printed)

Comment: If it was throwing (I guess it should) you can run under gdb and break on exceptions. This should stop you right in a place where problem is detected.

Comment: How can I check if a value is legal (either gdb or inside the code)? I  suspect that I have took away the pointer from the vector but the end iterator was not updated...

Comment: According to error message you are comparing some invalid iterator with **end** iterator. The only place where it happens is `while (fooit != foosBoxes[x][y][z].end()){`. So I guess at some point iterator `fooit` becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
//some stuff which does not have an effect on fooit;
```

But does the stuff have any effect on foosBoxes[x][y][z]?
In particular does it remove elements or cause a vector relocation?  If so, fooit cannot be compared meaningfully to foosBoxes[x][y][z].end().

Also, what happens to aFoo in the loop?  If this gets an invalid value, an assignment to it later will cause undefined behaviour.

Try removing the `some stuff` from the loop. If that works the stuff contains a bug. If the loop still fails, the cause must be an invalid value in fooxBoxes[] before you enter the loop

I have no experience with ValGrind. But I have used similar products. Please check that you have configured ValGrind to its most strict settings. This might make using it painfully slow, but hopefully finds the bug.

Comment: My experience with valgrind is almost as limited as yours... fooBoxes doesn't changed during the loop but might be changed elsewhere and has an effect. I'm checking the second now.

Comment: OK, I have added a loop to run before the main loop, please read my update to the question

Comment: I have to agree- this looks to me like you're causing that vector to reallocate and busting the iterators.

Comment: @DeadMG: I tried to iterate in the other direction and the program did not crush in the first iteration. Please read my addition to the question. I also have iterated through all the ``foo``s (separate vector) and nothing crushed there. Do you happen to know how can I print content of a vector int gdb?

Answer (score 0):

You're code as it is looks okay, the only thing I can think is that are `x` `y` `z` valid? `operator[]` does no bounds checking...

Comment: I would test that by using `at()` rather than the operator... may be revealing...

Answer (score -1):

To operate on an element of `foosBoxes[x][y][z]` you can also try:

```
while (fooit != foosBoxes[x][y][z].end()){
      vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> > *aFoo = *fooit; 
       fooit++;
      //To use the object 
     // use it as   aFoo->method()  
 }
```

Not sure if i am making the point. But i am currently using pointers to iterate in my objects.