# What is the difference between valgrind and regular c++ run

Tags: c++, debugging, valgrind

I'm trying to identify a [bug in I have in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090367/assigning-value-from-a-vector-of-shared-pointer-to-a-shared-pointer-cause-segme) where I get seg. fault while trying to assign value to a pointer from a vector (it is describe better in the link). When I run the code using valgrind I don't get the seg.fault.

What does valgrind do differently. I think that I need to consider the memory management differences between valgrind session and regular c++ session but I don't really know

Comment: If I have passed some law where you can't link to your own open question please let me know and I'll remove the question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with linking to other questions.  The only rule is that questions shouldn't duplicate the topic of other questions.

Comment: Are you using threading? IIRC Valgrind handles threads differently than running normally.

Comment: I don't think I'm using threading (I don't try to), could it be that the -march=core2 does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes):

> 4.4.  My program crashes normally, but doesn't under Valgrind, or vice
>   versa. What's happening?
>
> When a program runs under Valgrind, its environment is slightly
>   different to when it runs natively. For example, the memory layout is
>   different, and the way that threads are scheduled is different.
>
> Most of the time this doesn't make any difference, but it can,
>   particularly if your program is buggy. For example, if your program
>   crashes because it erroneously accesses memory that is unaddressable,
>   it's possible that this memory will not be unaddressable when run
>   under Valgrind. Alternatively, if your program has data races, these
>   may not manifest under Valgrind.
>
> There isn't anything you can do to change this, it's just the nature
>   of the way Valgrind works that it cannot exactly replicate a native
>   execution environment. In the case where your program crashes due to a
>   memory error when run natively but not when run under Valgrind, in
>   most cases Memcheck should identify the bad memory operation.

So you can nothing to do with it. Actually you need not worry that you program not crashes under Valgrind. You should read error messages from it and fix them. Start with [Invalid read/Invalid write errors](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.badrw). They are almost always indicate the bug in code. In this particular case you can also run your code in infinite loop from simple bash script utill it produces error message. Most likely you are working with invalid iterators and it is **Undefined Behaviour** in C++.

Comment: So... I should, actually figure out all those conditional jump and so. I'll try to use the -var thingy

Comment: OK. I have a suspect value (read/invalid). I think that there is a case where I'm trying to take the negative exponent of a very large number. How can I verify/fix this?

Comment: Comment it out to verify this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue might be timing dependent, When you run your code with valgrind it runs a little slower because valgrind collects and diagnoses your code at run time.

Comment: You mean that the computer update the iterator/integer before it tries to read the data?

Comment: No I don't mean that, I mean If your code has an issue which is timing dependent, It might slip through while running the valgrind. I am not sure How valgrind does the diagnonsis but it does sure introduces some delay that might cause an timing issue to slip through & work.

Comment: I don't think I have any. could it be that the -march=core2 cause that?

Comment: @Yotam: Are you sure you don't have any? Any multithreaded code is usually timing dependent as well.

Comment: I don't think I have. I didn't try to and I didn't implement anything from boost apart from shared_ptr. Could it be this? I tried to remove march and id didn't has any affect.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind keeps track of your programs memory usage. This is how it tells you about leaks. What this means is that it hijacks the `malloc` and such and uses its own so that it can achieve this. This means that probably when you run your code normally you read/write to some data you have freed accidentally causing segfault whereas it could be that valgrind is keeping this memory around to see if it is truly lost etc thereby meaning by (un)luck the memory is still valid. Just a guess.

Comment: ‎That sound probable. Is there a way to shut this off?

Comment: Erm, if you want to use valgrind I wouldn't imagine so but it should warn you about where you are accessing memory you shouldn't; try the option `--leak-check=full` (I think that is correct). Once you have tracked down where you are reading/writing where you shouldn't you can eliminate it from your code and it should run normally.

Comment: @Yotam have you considered using gdb to find the bug? It doesn't sound like the leak is the biggest of your worries.

Comment: I did use gdb. The results are described in the link I have placed in my question. The reason I consider valgrind is because it survive the seg. fault.

Comment: but why do you want to survive the segfault? gdb should let you examine the stack and see the value of variables leading up to the fault.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind runs you program on a virtual CPU, that is, it executes every assembly instruction in software (apart from kernel calls). Multi-threaded programs get serialized, i.e. only one thread of execution is making progress at one time.

If your application is multi-threaded, when it is executed under valgrind race condition and the lack of synchronization may be masked by the thread serialization, so that the effects of such bugs are not observed.